# ElementRef changed after click event

Tags: angular

my scenario is as following:
I have 3 components: MainComponent,ComponentA,ComponentB

MainComponent is dymamic loading ComponentA.
ComponentA has a button that onClick call MainComponent.addComponent(ComponentB)

```
export class MainLayout
  {
    constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader,private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    ///this will work fine
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(ComponentA,elementRef);
    }


    addComponent(component:Type) {
     ///this will fail 
      this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(component, this.elememtRef,'child1');
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:
You can see that the error is form the elementRef object....

> Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '_view' of undefined
>   ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '_view' of undefined
>       at Object.internalView (http://localhost:63342/decisionApp/decision-modeling-ui/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:6236:19)
>       at AppViewManager_.getNamedElementInComponentView (http://localhost:63342/decisionApp/decision-modeling-ui/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11240:33)
>       at DynamicComponentLoader_.loadIntoLocation (http://localhost:63342/decisionApp/decision-modeling-ui/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:14547:62)
>       at MainLayout.resolveComponent (http://localhost:63342/decisionApp/decision-modeling-ui/app/playground/ui-composition/mainLayout.js:32:18)
>       at ComponentsList.onClick (http://localhost:63342/decisionApp/decision-modeling-ui/app/playground/ui-composition/ComponentsList.js:25:20)

Comment: Why would you use a global var? Do you route away and back to the component in between?

Comment: I changed my question to be more clearer...

Comment: Did you see that you have a typo? `this.elememtRef` != `this.elementRef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out,
The reason I had different objectRefs is that I set a providers:[MainComponent] at the ComponenetA config.
this created for me a new instance of MainComponent.
and therefore a new instance of ElementRef that was injected in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your describtion is not very clear, because you don't tell us the failure message and some other things about your components. So I can only guess:

Something of component, this.elememtRef,'child1' is not present at the time you call addComponent and so it will fail? Maybe ComponentA has not already been completly loaded?
I also assume that "component" means ComponentB ?